# Angularway to detect when a div becomes visible on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, jquery-waypoints

I would like triggering an animation when the user is coming to the div which contains the animation. I tried with waypoint and it worked but now I want to try a pure angular solution.

Different options I've found are the following :

- angular-waypoint
- triggering the event on mouseenter/mouseleave
- constantly looking for the position and the scrollbar.

I am not asking for a solution already made, but rather advices!

Thank you.

Comment: Strictly, Come with Code!

Comment: You can use broadcast events from the element which is showing. Although don't abuse broadcast/emit events since they trigger the digest cicle

Comment: I didn't know this technique! Thank you :)